# Using interfaces as parameter arguments

Tags: apex, parameters, interface

Is it possible to use interfaces as parameters within Apex?

As an example:

```
public interface InterfaceExample{
    void example(InterfaceExample ex); // Will not compile
    InterfaceExample example2(String str); // Will compile
}

public class ConcreteExample implements InterfaceExample{
    // Does not compile if this is present :( 
    public void example(ConcreteExample ex){
        // ...
    }

    // Will compile and work just fine
    public ConcreteExample example2(String str){
        // ...
    }
}
```

I have tried using `Object` which doesn't work either :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tried to create the same interface and class. It was a success. You need to change in class `ConcreteExample` parameter type of `example` method to `InterfaceExample`, as this is declared in interface. However, for `example2` method you can leave return type as `ConcreteExample`. The following code is compiling.

Interface:

```
public interface InterfaceExample{
    void example(InterfaceExample ex);
    InterfaceExample example2(String str);
}
```

Class:

```
public class ConcreteExample implements InterfaceExample{

    public void example(InterfaceExample ex){
    }

    public ConcreteExample example2(String str){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does work well, makes it possible to have ConcreteExample.example(...) take objects it wasn't intended to take, but that's not the end of the world, thanks!